# Querystring for Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am making the following get request to Paypal Sandbox. But it says some problem with merchant account.

Is there any way that i can see what i am sending wrong? Here is the request URL

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=raheel.exile@gmail.com&invoice=1949&currency_code=USD&item_name=localhost&item_number=1&quantity=1&amount=100.00&return=http://localhost/drupal/user/register&cancel_return=http://localhost/drupal/paypal/cancel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You are missing one of the variables:
The string should be :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=raheel.exile@gmail.com&invoice=1949&currency_code=USD&item_name=localhost&item_number=1&quantity=1&amount=100.00&return=http://localhost/drupal/user/register&cancel_return=http://localhost/drupal/paypal/cancel&add=1

`add=1` is missing

Check the variables associated with `cart` command [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Comment: I added it but then it says you have empty cart. I replaced item_name to item_name_1, item_number to item_number_1 and amount to amount_1 and now its working fine. I just copied paste but didn't get the concept. Can you please guide me

Comment: `item_name_x` variable applies only for add to cart button with `_cart=upload`, there are different variable that applies when _cart value changes (add,upload,display)

Comment: btw, the above link i posted in the answer is working as intended.

Comment: yes you are right. the _cart=upload i was using. Thanks alot